# Fastest way to 'ignore' a row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am writing a PL/SQL function that processes table rows individually.  I pass it a key.  What is the fastest way to check whether or not that row has been processed, and if so ignore it?  It may sound stupid but please assume that it always tries to process all the rows in the table (mainly because it does other things too).

One solution I had was to create a flag column on that table(fastest I can think of), another was to insert a record into another table and check if the row is not in that table (probably slower).

Comment: what is the function supposed to do? you should specify an order based on column(s). as posted the question is too broad. you may not actually need PL/SQL to do this. post some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @vkp Updated my question.

Comment: If you care about speed, then find a way to eliminate using the cursor.  Your processing does not suggest the need for a cursor.

Comment: Sorry, I am not explaining myself well.  I have updated my question.

Comment: To have a _process status_-column in the row. The select statement (in `where`-clause) ignores the non-wanted rows and thus rest of your processing logic doesn't need to check the status. However the logic have to update status in the end. That might be tricky in error situations. The name of the column and the values that describe the processing status is up to your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to be using a PL/SQL function, you should only pass into it the rowset that it needs to handle.  That means using plain SQL to select the rows from the table you need and pass that to the function.  In any case though, you should look very carefully at what you're doing whenever you end up having to use a cursor in a database environment, because that's not really what databases are optimized for.

Comment: This is a kind of contradiction to the beginning of your answer: _"look very carefully at what you're doing whenever you end up having to use a cursor in a database environment, because that's not really what databases are optimized for"_. In PL/SQL all select statements are cursors (either implicit or explicit) and thus using cursors is essential and optimal way to do processing in PL/SQL.

Comment: I meant that using pl/sql instead of regular sql at all is usually not necessary.  I meant to watch out for using a cursor to iterate over a result set row by row.

Comment: We are not allowed to execute 'regular' sql in our production instance, only procedures and functions.

Comment: What?  You don't have any views?  How does your application interact with the db?